# Diferencia entre fechas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos fechas sobre las cuales necesito saber cuanto es la diferencia de años entre ambas, segun entiendo con el DATEDIFF se puede hacer, estoy siguiendo un curso de SQL y no se mucho del tema, si alguien podria explicarme el funcionamiento le agradeceria mucho

Comment: Lee [la documentación](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-datediff-function/)

Answer (score 1):

El `DATEDIFF()` es una funcion que te permite sacar diferencia de dias, meses o años entre dos fechas, para hacer lo que pides seria algo asi

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS Diferencia;
```

Igual te dejo la documentacion para que la leas y te adentres mas sobre el uso que le puedes dar

[DATEDIFF](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-datediff-function/)

Answer (score 1):

El DATEDIFF() te puede servir puedes sacar la diferencia de diad,meses hasta  años esp lo especificas antes del primer coma como se muestra en el ejemplo

SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2020/02/27', '2023/02/27') AS Diferencia;

Answer (score 0):

Hay que entender correctamente como funciona DATEDIFF, ya que solo calcula saltos entre distintos periodos y no es una forma exacta para calcular número de años. Dejo un ejemplo con su explicación para que veas la diferencia entre el resultado simple de DATEDIFF y un cálculo correcto de edad (o años completos).

```
SELECT FechaInicio, FechaFin,
       DATEDIFF( YY, FechaInicio, FechaFin) AS SoloDateDiff,
       DATEDIFF( YY, FechaInicio, FechaFin) --Obtenemos el número de veces que ha cambiado el año
        - CASE WHEN DATEADD( YY, DATEDIFF(YY, FechaInicio, FechaFin), FechaInicio) > FechaFin --Sumamos la cantidad de años a la fecha inicial
                THEN 1 -- Si la fecha inicial queda mayor entonces no se ha completado un año y le restamos uno
                ELSE 0 -- Si no, mantenemos la diferencia completa
                END AS CalculoExacto
FROM( VALUES( CAST( '20191231' AS DATE), CAST( '20200101' AS DATE)),
            ( CAST( '20190101' AS DATE), CAST( '20201231' AS DATE)),
            ( CAST( '19851006' AS DATE), CAST( '20200227' AS DATE)),
            ( CAST( '19850116' AS DATE), CAST( '20200227' AS DATE)),
            ( CAST( '20200116' AS DATE), CAST( '20200227' AS DATE)))x(FechaInicio, FechaFin)
```